# Improve/Parametrize SQL query with unknown characters

Tags: python, mysql

How to escape quotes and double quotes in SQL. I have the following statement:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE contents LIKE '%user_input%'
```

However, the user can enter anything, it can have a single quote, double quote, etc. Is there a way to escape any quotations entered by the user? The equivalent of doing the following in python?

```
'''%s''' % user_input
```

Answer (score 0):

By manually escaping the single quotation, it seems to get around this:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM mapping WHERE minified_contents LIKE %s",  
    '%' + user_input.replace("'", "\'") + '%')
```